# Pasar Focus entre Botones

Tags: java, netbeans, botón, scroll, eventos

aun que parezca algo muy sencillo, ps me esta creando problemas...
tengo una ventana en donde eh implementado un ScrollPane y dentro de el un panel. mas botones y una tabla (hasta ahí todo bien). Lo que quiero es que cuando doy clic en un botón este me pase con el enter al otro botón y así sucesivamente pero conforme voy pasando los botones el ScrollPane se vaya moviendo sin la necesidad de que yo misma con el mouse tenga que moverlo para ver el resto de botones, si no que conforme voy enfocando los botones y estos pasan de uno a otro el ScrollPane también se mueva y se visualice todo.

Les dejo una imagen (y un poco explicación para ser más exactos)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para los que tienen problemas parecidos a los mios y no saben como resolverlo aqui les dejo la respuesta. :)

En mi caso, queria que conforme vaya moviendo los botones y demás cajas de texto, etc. Se vaya moviendo tambien junto a ello mi `JScrollPane` entonces pensaba que con el focus, este pasaría también por defecto. Pero no fué asi, entonces investigando llegue  a lo siguiente. Necesita si el focus para que pase de una caseta a otra pero lo que me faltaba añadir era el movimiento de mi `JScrollPane`, para que juntos se muevan los dos.

**1. Darle la acción a mi caja (se obtiene al dar doble clic en un boton):**

```
private void mibotonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  miboton.requestFocus(true);
}
```

**2. Darle movimiento a mi ScrollPane (hay dos formas):**

```
//Que baje de uno el ScrollPane (hasta el final)
miscroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(miscroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());

//Que baje de a poquitos (calcular la distancia entre cajas)
miscroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(10);//el 10 se refiere a la cantidad de espacio que quiere que baje
```